# Weird thing occurred when porting isometric tiled map from cocos2d for iPhone to cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am trying to convert some Cocos2d-iphone code to Cocos2d-x code but some weird things happened with isometric tiled map.
The ground becomes totally dark.Please help me.

In Objective-C:

> -(id) init { if ((self = [super init])) { CCTMXTiledMap* tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"isometric-with-border.tmx"];
>   [self addChild:tileMap z:-1 tag:TileMapNode];
>
> CCTMXLayer* layer = [tileMap layerNamed:@"Collisions"]; layer.visible
>   = NO;
>
> // Use a negative offset to set the tilemap's start position
>   tileMap.position = CGPointMake(-500, -500); …. } }

In C++:

> bool TiledMap::init() {  if ( !CCLayer::init() ) { return false; }
>   CCTMXTiledMap *tileMap =
>   CCTMXTiledMap::create("isometric-with-border.tmx");
>   this->addChild(tileMap,1,TileMapNode);
>
> CCTMXLayer* layer = tileMap->layerNamed("Collisions");
>   layer->setVisible(false);
>
> // Use a negative offset to set the tilemap's start position
>   tileMap->setPosition(-500, -500); …. }

Comment: In objc, your z-value is -1.  In C++, it's 1. Check that first..